# Field from database not displaying in browser

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me why I am not getting the result of displaying the title on the browser when using the following script:

```
$sql =mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM 'Tour' WHERE 'Tour_No.'=1 LIMIT 0, 30 ");

echo $sql Title;
```

my connection is successful, but my desired result is not happening.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `Tour` WHERE `Tour_No.`=1 LIMIT 0, 30 ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
{    
  echo $row->Title;
  echo '<br />';
}
```

Maybe you can check this link  for more  example using `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_object` :

1. mysql_query: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
2. mysql_fetch_object: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I now have a working script. As sh4nx0r said it would be useful toknow what I did wrong.

Comment: @StephenCoulson: Updated my answer with link to PHP Manual.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your Query is invalid (single quotes are not used for tables / columns):

   `$result = mysql_query("SELECT Title FROM Tour WHERE Tour_No = 1 LIMIT 1");`
2. You have to fetch the results:

   `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`
3. Output the title:

   `echo $row['Title'];`

Answer (score 0):

Table and field names can be put in backtics, not in single quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM `Tour` WHERE `Tour_No.`=1 LIMIT 0, 30 // correct
SELECT * FROM 'Tour' WHERE 'Tour_No.'=1 LIMIT 0, 30  // wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Knew it would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

if your getting 30 results you will need to loop through $sql, try the following.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Tour` WHERE `Tour_No.` = 1 LIMIT 0, 30 ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo $row['Title'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/mysql_query:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query()  returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error....
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data."

Try this:

```
$sql =mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM 'Tour' WHERE 'Tour_No.'=1 LIMIT 0, 30 ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo $row['Title'];
```

I'm not sure exactly what your columns are named, but that should get you on the right track.